# Все ссылки ведут на главную страницу сайта (Drupal)

Tags: drupal

29.04.2018, Воскресенье,  WalterScott
Предыстория: Было задание реализовать полноценный каталог с ценами, корзиной на сайте. Все выполнил с Drupal commerce. Все хорошо работало;

Получается примерно через неделю захожу на сайт, отображается он корректно, но абсолютно все ссылки ведут(загружают) главную страницу. При чем получается в адресной строке переход происходит, то есть ссылка меняется, допустим example.com/catalog, но при этом загружается главная страница. Что еще заметил, что ссылки рода example.com/?q=user/login загружаются нормально, но некоторые сразу выключаются. Админкой сайта пользоваться невозможно. Как-то так

Любая помощь приветствуется, заранее Большое спасибо!!

Comment: Скинь файл .htaccess

Comment: это ничего особенного, просто clean_url нужно правильно настроить

Comment: да, вот уже разбираюсь, еще раз спасибо